# Root Android then Restore Factory Defaults

Tags: rooting, factory-reset

If one roots an Android device (smartphone), what happens when Factory data reset is performed after that? Will the device remain rooted?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by resetting the phone:

1. A Full wipe / factory reset using the recovery system will not remove root. You flashed root into the /system/ partition, so it isn't going anywhere if you just wipe the data from the device.
2. Re-installing official firmware will remove root (e.g., re-flashing a stock ROM)